# Performance concern due to serilog eventcollector

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I'm considering to use serilog for my app. We have .net core 2.1 app.
Want to push application logs to splunk. So I've options where I can use Serilog.Sinks.Splunk and push logs WriteTo.EventCollector (specific index is configured in splunk)
Another option is I can write logs to files using witeto.File and use forwarder logs can be available in splunk.

Configuration looks like

```
    Serilog.Core.Logger logger= new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .WriteTo.EventCollector(<host>,<token> ,new CompactSplunkJsonFormatter())
        .CreateLogger();
```

In this regard need suggestion

1. Which of the above approaches are better?
2. Is there any performance difference of `WriteTo.EventCollector` Vs `witeto.File` in serilog?
3. Can there be any performance  impact if I use above configuration? Any more configuration can be used along with this for better performance?